# Odoo 14 overriding method

Tags: module, overriding, odoo, odoo-14

I'm trying to create an Odoo module which override Sales order confirm button. I followed the information I found, and I created the following code, but it doesn't work.

```py
from odoo import models, fields, api
import logging
_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__) 

class saleoverride(models.Model):
    _name = 'saleoverride.saleoverride'
    _description = 'saleoverride'
    _inherit = 'sale.order'

    name = fields.Char()
    # value = fields.Integer()
    # value2 = fields.Float(compute="_value_pc", store=True)
    description = fields.Text()

    transaction_ids = fields.Many2many('payment.transaction', 'saleoverride_transaction_rel', 'saleoverride_id', 'transaction_id',
                                   string='Transactions', copy=False, readonly=True)
    tag_ids = fields.Many2many('crm.tag', 'saleoverride_tag_rel', 'saleoverride_id', 'tag_id', string='Tags')

    @api.model
    def action_confirm(self):
        res = super(SaleOrder, self).action_confirm()
        _logger.info("saleoverride_action_confirm")
        _logger.info(self)
        return res
```

I tried to search the message in the log file, but can't find anything. Can someone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not extending the `sale.order` model, but creating a new one (`saleoverride.saleoverride`) based on `sale.order`.

Check odoo docs: [Inheritance and extension](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/reference/orm.html#inheritance-and-extension)

```py
from odoo import models, fields, api
import logging
_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__) 

class saleoverride(models.Model):
    _description = 'saleoverride'
    _inherit = 'sale.order'

    name = fields.Char()
    # value = fields.Integer()
    # value2 = fields.Float(compute="_value_pc", store=True)
    description = fields.Text()

    transaction_ids = fields.Many2many('payment.transaction', 'saleoverride_transaction_rel', 'saleoverride_id', 'transaction_id',
                                   string='Transactions', copy=False, readonly=True)
    tag_ids = fields.Many2many('crm.tag', 'saleoverride_tag_rel', 'saleoverride_id', 'tag_id', string='Tags')

    def action_confirm(self):
        res = super(SaleOrder, self).action_confirm()
        _logger.info("saleoverride_action_confirm")
        _logger.info(self)
        return res
```

Removing `_name = 'saleoverride.saleoverride'` from your class adds new features to `sale.order`.

Also remove the decorator since the original function doesn't have one.

Comment: Could you please add a hint why you've removed `api.model` above the method? Because that's correct but should be also noted in the answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

When you want to override the code in addons, all you can do is just inheriting it. So, you can't define name while overriding the existing code.
Remove:
_name ='saleoverride.saleoverride'